# JQuery How to keep detecting textarea resize when mouse goes out of control area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 textareas that needs to vertically resize together.

However, when mouse goes out of the control area, the function stops working correctly (it doesn't see the `mousemove` anymore).

[image]

What can I do to have the 2 textareas resize together even if the mouse is out of the control area?

```js
$('#t').mousemove(function(){$('#b').css('height',$(this).css('height'));});

$('#b').mousemove(function(){$('#t').css('height',$(this).css('height'));});
```

```css
textarea {
    resize:vertical;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://static.jsbin.com/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <textarea id="t"></textarea>
  <textarea id="b"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this does not answer your title's question, but it should achieve the same goal as your overall question. I would recommend looking at using a [mutation observer](https://caniuse.com/#search=mutation%20observer) instead of a mouse move listener. In this example 
I created a helper function that takes a `master` and `puppet` element. It will observe the `master` for `style` (including height and width) changes and sets the `puppet`'s width and height

The `6` that I subtract from the width and height seem to be the border + margin + padding of the textbox, you can likely compute that dynamically but for this demo I was only concerned with making them work with default styling.

```js
function syncSize(master, puppet) {
  // Create a temporary callback that uses the puppet and master 
  let sync = function() {
    let width = master.offsetWidth - 6;
    let height = master.offsetHeight - 6;
    puppet.style.width = `${width}px`;
    puppet.style.height = `${height}px`;
  }
  
  // Return a new observer with the callback that listens to the master
  return new MutationObserver(sync).observe(master, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ["style"]
  });
}

syncSize(left, right);
syncSize(right, left);
```

```html
<textarea id="left">Resize me</textarea>
<textarea id="right">I sync</textarea>
```

Comment: How would I setup the function if I have groups of textareas that are independent of eachother? For example, I have `left1` & `right1`, `left2` & `right2`. I'm assuming I can pass through `syncLeft('left1')` but how do I pass `left1` to the `MutationObserver`?

Comment: For example, this: https://jsbin.com/nozamulono/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I edited it to be more generic and created a helper function that takes a `master` and `puppet` element. Here's your updated jsbin https://jsbin.com/tufaruyinu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks for that, it works beautifully. One last question, how do I implement it within the `onclick` event? I tried it here but couldn't seem to get it to work: https://jsbin.com/jokuhomema/1/edit?html,css,js,output. It looks like there's no javascript error either.

Comment: Why would you need to make it listen only when clicking? The only reason I could think of was performence, so I tested it with 100 `textbox` elements and the browser has no problem. https://jsbin.com/bolovexuca/edit?html,css,js,output
I also tried to add it with the `onclick` event and didn't have any luck, I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with using attributes for callbacks so I'm not sure how to make it work.

Comment: The beauty of working as a collective consciousness, it's resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57419200/javascript-using-attributes-for-callbacks-with-onclick-event/57419456#57419456. Thanks for laying down the ground work.