# Javascript: Using attributes for callbacks with onclick event

Tags: javascript

Because I have 2 `textarea` dynamically generated and I need to resize them in pairs. How would I get this callback function to work with the `onclick` event? I believe this is a scoping problem based on a google search.

```js
function syncSize(master, puppet) {
  // Create a temporary callback that uses the puppet and master 
  let sync = function() {
    let height = master.offsetHeight - 6;
    puppet.style.height = `${height}px`;
  }
  
  // Return a new observer with the callback that listens to the master
  return new MutationObserver(sync).observe(master, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ["style"]
  });
}

//this will work if uncommented
//syncSize(left, right)
//syncSize(right, left)

//syncSize(left1, right1)
//syncSize(right1, left1)
```

```css
textarea{
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="left" onclick="syncSize(left, right)">Resize me</textarea>
<textarea id="right" onclick="syncSize(right, left)">I sync</textarea>
  <br/>
<textarea id="left1" onclick="javascript:syncSize(left1, right1);">Resize me</textarea>
<textarea id="right1" onclick="javascript:syncSize(right1, left1);">I sync</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

In case `jquery` `mousemove` is suggested, I prefer not to use this due to limitations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415805/jquery-how-to-keep-detecting-textarea-resize-when-mouse-goes-out-of-control-area).

Comment: onclick is ambiguous, I'd try onmouseup to differentiate from potentially triggering equivalent to onmousedown

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are having trouble detecting the resize for the textareas, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937721/how-to-detect-textarea-size-change-with-pure-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```js
function create(master, puppet){
  function sync(){

    puppet.style.height = master.style.height
    puppet.style.width = master.style.width
  }
  var obs;
  try {
    obs = new ResizeObserver(sync)
    obs.observe(master);
  } catch {
    obs = new MutationObserver(sync)
    obs.observe(master, {
      attributes: true,
      attributeFilter: ["style"]
    });
  }
  master.onmouseup = () => {
    obs.disconnect();
    master.onmouseup = () => null
  }
}
```

```css
textarea{
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="master" onmousedown="create(master, puppet)">Resize me</textarea>
<textarea id="puppet" onmousedown="create(puppet, master)">I sync</textarea>
  <br/>
<textarea id="left1" onmousedown="create(left1, right1);">Resize me</textarea>
<textarea id="right1" onclick="create(right1, left1);">I sync</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note, I used `MutationObserver` as a response to sojim2's previous question because `ResizeObserver` doesn't have a [lot of support](https://caniuse.com/#search=resize%20observer) yet

Comment: @GammaGames well i have no context - but to discard a feature due to lacking upgrades seems ... - one has to consider and make fallbacks - but the issue here was onmousedown, onmouseup, onclick or how textare resize works - and my answer still has flaws - but its not for production so its reduced to whats essential

Comment: I was only noting that it currently does not have support. Browsers evolve quickly, give it a year and I'm sure it will be supported by most (if not all) modern browsers.

Comment: @GammaGames - i am braindead fixed it for all the other SO users - thx